# Undetstanding the Torch Cosine Similarity along Different Dimensions

Tags: python, pytorch

I have two tensors:

```
a = tensor([[1., 2., 3., 5.],
        [1., 9., 9., 5.]])

b = tensor([[ 7.,  8.,  9.,  5.],
        [10., -1.,  3.,  5.]])
```

I can not understand why calculating the cosine similarity along *dim = 0* results in a tensor with 4 distances:

```
tensor([0.9848, 0.0942, 0.6000, 1.0000])
```

Calculating in dim = 0 should have collapsed [1., 2., 3., 5.] and [ 7.,  8.,  9.,  5.], also [1., 9., 9., 5.] and [10., -1.,  3.,  5.] and then calculated the distance between [1., 2., 3., 5.] and [ 7.,  8.,  9.,  5.], and then between [1., 9., 9., 5.] and [10., -1.,  3.,  5.].

However, it seems that it collapses [1,1] and [7, 10], calculates the similarity between them, and then does the same for [2, 9] and [8, -1],...

The complete code:

```
a = torch.as_tensor([[1,2, 3, 5], [1,9, 9, 5]]).float()
b = torch.as_tensor([[7, 8, 9, 5], [10, -1, 3, 5]]).float()
F.cosine_similarity(a, b, dim = 0)
```

Comment: Can you provide the code you using to calculate the cosine?

Comment: Sure..

a = torch.as_tensor([[1,2, 3, 5], [1,9, 9, 5]]).float()

b = torch.as_tensor([[7, 8, 9, 5], [10, -1, 3, 5]]).float()

F.cosine_similarity(a, b, 0)

Comment: I edited my question and added the complete code.

Comment: This seems to be a convention issue. Torch appears to consider the `dim` parameter as the dimension alongside the similarity will be calculated (in this case, it calculates the similarity along the rows, in other words, the similiarity between the columns that composes each element of the row). From the [documentation][1] it reads "dim: Dimension where cosine similarity is computed". So calculating the similarity on the rows implies calculating the distance between the column vectors.


  [1]: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CosineSimilarity.html

Comment: Could you explain more, please? I can't understand why this convention is different from what we see in toch.cat(), sum(), ...